# Google Ads API - items manage outstock

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-ads-api

I have a question about manage items stock / outstock google ads
I've tried to use Google Scripts - but it decision not matched for me, because page code site has often change by developers
Google Ads API - is it decisions for my requirement?
Someone use it for manage ads - for stop ads if items outstock?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a good use case for the Ads Api.

I'd recommend you start with the API quick start: https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/first-call/overview

Comment: Hello, Dave. Thanks for response. Could I ask for myself, if I right understand - some ready decisions ads manage outstock items isn't exist. I need build my API - with exist Google Ads API inventory

Comment: Yes, you need to integrate your own inventory system with the API. Best of luck!